# C++: Find right triangle algorithm is not getting the result expected

Tags: c++, function, class

everyone. I've spent quite a few hours now, trying to write a function that will exhaustively search for all right triangles with perimeters within a certain range. To clarify, the function makes use of a class defined in a header file as triangles, as such:

```
/*
 * triangles.h
 * Header file for triangle class.
*/
// make sure this file is not included multiple times:
#pragma once

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

class triangle {
    public:
        // member functions:
        // constructor (this is an inline version):
        triangle(unsigned long a=3, unsigned long b=4, unsigned long c=5):
        s1(a),s2(b),s3(c) {}
    unsigned long perimeter();
    unsigned long area();
    void print();  // prints to standard output
    // member variables:
    // integers for the 3 sides:
    unsigned long s1;
    unsigned long s2;
    unsigned long s3;
};

vector<triangle> findRightTriangles(unsigned long l, unsigned long h);
bool congruent(triangle t1, triangle t2);
bool similar(triangle t1, triangle t2);
```

The function findRightTriangles is the function from the implementation file that needs to be completed. Thus far, I have this:

```
vector<triangle> findRightTriangles(unsigned long l, unsigned long h) {
    // TODO: find all the right triangles with integer sides,
    // subject to the perimeter bigger than l and less than h
    vector<triangle> retval; // storage for return value.
    unsigned long a = 1, b = 1, c = l;

    for (a = 1; h >= (a+b+c); a++) { //perimeter a+b+c is less than h

        if (((a*a) + (b*b)) == (c*c)) { //check if a, b, and c are sides of a right triangle, then plug them into retval.
            triangle t1(a,b,c);
            retval.push_back(t1);
    }

        for (b = 1; h >= (a+b+c); b++) { //go through values of b for right triangles.

            if (((a*a) + (b*b)) == (c*c)) {
                triangle t1(a,b,c);
                retval.push_back(t1);
            }

            for (c = l; h >= (a+b+c); c++) {

                if (((a*a) + (b*b)) == (c*c)) {
                    triangle t1(a,b,c);
                    retval.push_back(t1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return retval;
}
```

However, in main.cpp, when I call the function, it doesn't return anything. I've tried time and time again to follow the logic, but I can't see where the function fails. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a full (but minimal) set of compilable code that exhibits the problem, so that we can help you debug.

Comment: Too much code to bother with. Reduce the amount of code you have posted and show exactly which value(s) is not what you are expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of your `for (c...` loop, c will be such that `h >= (a+b+c)` is false. When you then loop around to test `h >= (a+b+c)` in the `for (b...` loop, it will immediately fail. Try either setting `c` to 1 after the for loop (and the same for `b`), or changing your for loops to

```
for (a = 1; h >= (a+1+1); a++) { //perimeter a+b+c is less than h
```

so you aren't testing b and c when they are at their maximum.